# Can I access the browser cache from a SWF in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Is it possible to read data from the browser cache from within a SWF?  I don't **think** this is possible since SOP could be easily side-stepped.  Thanks!

Comment: There are Flash cookies (which are implemented through instances of the `SharedObject` class that aren't actually shared between computers).  That really doesn't count as the browser cache, and it doesn't really include things like cached websites and stuff, but if you're just wanting to do some real simple I/O with either the browser cache or something similar to it, that may be the route to go.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use JavaScript with the `ExternalInterface` class in AS3 to use conventional cookies, which are a part of the browser cache.  Some browsers require you to wrap the swf in an HTML page or something to really use `ExternalInterface` though.

Comment: What do you need to get out of the cache? Like Panzercrisis mentioned, if you need to store data for later use you could store data as a cookie and access with js or use a shared object(less effective). You won't have direct access to browser cache in any language in a web app, it would have to be installed in-browser or the OS for filesystem access.